# WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run an ionic app on my mobile phone (Android 4.4.2).
USB-Debugging is activated.

When i run the command **"ionic emulate android"** everything works fine and the app is opend in the emulator.

But when I run the commad **"ionic run android"** I get following warning:

**WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator**

and the app is started on the virtual device...

Shouldn't the app run on my mobile phone? What am I doing wrong?
How can I specify the target?

P.S.: When I copy the .apk file to the phone I can run the app.

Comment: guess: your phone is not configured for debugging

Comment: If you phone is configured for debuggin, disable and enable again. It's worked for me!

Comment: I have this sometimes using a Samsung phone and Ubuntu. Sometimes I need to unplug and plug in the cable and confirm 'Allow' in he dialog. Once I needed to restart Ubuntu for it to find the device again.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Here is what I did:
I typed into the command line: `adb devices` (located in the "platform-tools" folder in the Android SDK) which returned me an empty list.

So I installed my phone's drivers, which I downloaded from the vendors homepage.

Now the list contains my device and the app is started on my mobile phone.

Comment: A little tip.. You will need the driver, eg. google (for Sony you can download them here https://developer.sony.com/develop/drivers/ ). In windows you will also need to install the driver in device manager and make sure your phone is set up with developer mode, and from there enable usb-debugging

Comment: Just for reference, you need USB debugging on your phone turned on at the Developer Options for this to work!

Answer (score 64):

I had another developer tool opened (Chrome Inspect) and it "ate" the connection. In my case, just closing the Chrome Inspect panel and running `ionic run android` worked.

Answer (score 19):

I had a different problem, with a very simple solution.
When plugging in your Android device for the first time, it'll ask you to trust the computer's certificate. That popup screen disappeared on me, as I was just getting a call.

Simply unplugging/replugging your phone and accepting your computer's certificate should do the trick!

Answer (score 17):

Once you've enabled your device for debugging, make sure to turn on usb tethering on the device;

Settings > Tethering & Networks > USB tethering

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 16):

In my case I had Android 5.1.1, and below are the steps I took:

- Please check that your PC recognizes your phone (you can access the files like in a USB flash drive). If not please install the drivers from google [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html).
- Please check that the USB debugging options is checked on your phone, then:

  `1- Go to Setting -> General -> '{} Developer options'
  2- Look for the 'USB debugging' option
  3- If the 'USB debugging' option is disabled then turn off 'Developer options' and turn it back on. Now you should be able to check the 'USB debugging' option.`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

None of these worked for me on android 6.0 on a mac.

I found this article: http://trendblog.net/android-file-transfer-not-working/

quoting from it:

- Enable Developer Mode by going to Settings > About Phone (at the very bottom usually) > press on Build Number repeatedly until the pop-up appears
- Go to Settings > Developer Options
- Enable USB debugging

Comment: it's pretty weird, but you do have to tap on the build number repeatedly and then suddenly it says "you're a developer" before you see the settings to enable USB debugging.

Comment: Tnx. This was the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on a Mac.

What worked for me was to heed the warning on the device that said no program on the Mac was available that could connect to the device, such as Android File Transfer.

I installed that. Unplugged and replugged the USB cable. And voila.

Comment: 2019, ionic 3+ and answer is still valid! Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

I had two problems (Ubuntu OS):

1. I had a connection open with `chrome//inspect` - close that (simply close the tab)
2. I missed the dialog that appears when you connect your device through USB cable. You must trust the computer.

Now run the command `cordova run android` and look at your device there another dialog will be appeared click ok, now you are done! In the terminal you will see `LAUNCH SUCCESS`. By the way I removed the old app from my device too.

Answer (score 2):

No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
When this message appears, you have to click START, and activate your emulator before.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your app is already installed in your device and your device debuging is already enabled.

Then uninstall the previous app and install the fresh apk

```
sudo ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you are remove the USB plugin from the computer means it will not work. Already open the Chrome inspect in your PC means close that tab and run.
In my case, just closing the **Chrome Inspect** panel and running ionic cordova run android worked.

Thats all. Enjoy your coding

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution by removing the Android emulator and re-create the emulator from AVD Manager of Android Studio.