# I'm trying to run my first Ionic app but i'm getting this error where it does not find my phone and does not find the emulator to run either

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
$ ionic run android
```

result:

> No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
>
> Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
>   1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\Android\tools\android.bat" sdk
>   2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\Android\tools\android.bat" avd HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM
>   device driver

Comment: It clearly says that it cannot find any device to install the app. are you sure you have a device connected or an emulator running?

Comment: Check if you have set programmer opition on device (debuggable)

Comment: ok type adb devices in your terminal. if you see your device then its fine else download your device driver that might help you.

Comment: If you have not connected any device, can you check if an Android Simulator device is setup? If not, you can set it up using Android Studio.

Comment: Yes! @SMR i installed API 25 and i run my app through intelliJ

Comment: It's show VT-X is disable? I am using HP2000 Notebook couldn't find VT-x ? please anyone help me ?.

Comment: Nitesh Mishra it's show 25 API

Comment: In GIT Bash its show 25 API 7.0.1 nexus 5x

Comment: you do not make any sense. Is any android device is connected to the system via usb with USB debugging on? or Is any emulator is running? API level does not matter for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944494/warning-no-target-specified-deploying-to-emulator)

Comment: got it @SMR i have to enable my VT-x and now i run my program thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To run ionic run android command, you should have  android emulator installed. so install and run the command

If you still want to build app, you can connect your mobile to system, enable developer option in settings, then run the same command it will install into your mobile.

To enable developer option in your mobile: go to setting,developer option,enable checkbox USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this error is available emulator API version does not match with android platform version of your project. Try to add appropriate emulator using **`avdmanager`** and try to rerun.